# Creating a Retro-themed loading screen in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have an idea to include a loading screen, just for a fun project I'm working on, prior to starting the actual program in Python.

Back in the 80s, we had loading screens on the ZX Spectrum, and other 8-bit computers, that displayed an image one line at a time, then coloured the image in - something to look at while the game loaded. You can find an example at: https://youtu.be/MtBoRp_cSxQ

What I'd like to do is part-replicate this feature. I'd like to be able to take a JPG or PNG and have Python code to load it one line at a time, much in the same as the video in the link above. I don't mind if it can't be coloured in after, or that there's no funky raster bars in the borders. Just an image, 'loading' in at one line at a time (if you see what I mean).

I can achieve much the same effect in the console with some basic code, using a text file with ASCII art, but it'd be great with an actual image.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

As always, thanks in advance.

Dave.

```
import os
import time

def splash_screen(seconds):
    splash=open("test.txt", 'r')
    for lines in splash:
        print(lines)
        time.sleep(seconds)
    splash.close()



#Main Code Start
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
splash_screen(.5)

username=input("Type your username:")
```

Comment: hi, if you want to achieve this with an image, pygame might do the trick? or you want to have a final render as ascii art?

Comment: I was thinking Pygame, or perhaps Turtle? I've got it in my head that I'll need to hide the image, by putting blocks over it, then removing the blocks. Not sure how to get that stage though.